in discord js msg.attachments.first().name,all blank chars are replaced by an underbar, and if the underbar is present at the beginning, it disappears
Sorry my code is dirty
and also I'm not a native english speaker
~
As the title goes, all spaces in msg.attachments.first().name are replaced by underbars and disappear if there is an underbar in the first
when a user sends a file with "$fur2mp3" in the chat window, the file must be converted through an external script,
but before that, there is a problem in the process of finding the name of the file
if the name of the file user sends does not contain  underbar('_') or space (' '), everything works fine, but if it does not, it fails to find the file (there are no errors or crashes btw)
This is a list of the file names and their values that I tried
_kirb space.fur --> kirb_space.fur
_kirb sp_ace.fur --> kirb_sp_ace.fur
kirb space.fur --> kirb_space.fur

     commands.add('fur2mp3',() => {
    fs.exists('buffer_furrendering.txt',  function(exists){
        if(exists){
            msg.channel.send('Another file is being processed! Please wait!');      
        } else {

            if(msg.attachments.first()){//checks if an attachment is sent
            //arg = msg.attachments.first()
            msg.channel.send('Uploading...');

            download(msg.attachments.first().url, process.cwd());//Function

            msg.channel.send('Uploaded!');
    
    msg.channel.send(msg.attachments.first().name);

            fs.exists(msg.attachments.first().name,  function(exists){
            if(exists){
     
                msg.channel.send('Current Furnace Tracker Version : 0.6.5');
                msg.channel.send('Converting...');
                msg.channel.startTyping();
    exec('fur2wav.bat' + ' ' + msg.attachments.first().name, (error, stdout, stderr) =>{
                msg.channel.stopTyping();
    

                fs.readFile('buffer_fur2wavmsg.txt', 'utf8', (err, gwav) => {
                if (err) {

                    console.error(err);
                    return;
                }

            console.log(gwav);

            msg.channel.send(gwav);
            msg.channel.send({ files: ["furoutput.mp3"] });
     });
       });
        console.log("exixts! : ",exists);
        } else {
            msg.channel.stopTyping();
             msg.channel.send('The file does not exist!');
        }});
           } else { msg.channel.send('Send your file with this command!'); }
           
           
        };
    });
    });

I tried this, 'msg.attachments.first().name.join(' ')' but uhh I think i was wrong
No error, but the bot returns these
Uploading...
Uploaded!
kirb_sp_ace.fur
The file does not exist!
